# Use raspberry pi 3 as network switch?

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi, switch, gigabit-ethernet

I own a raspberry pi 3 with integrated wifi and I have several computers I would like to connect with ethernet cables for gigabit file transfers. Unfortunately the home's router is located on a different level of the house and there is NO chance of getting an ethernet cable from the router downstairs. I own a network switch.

I am wondering if it is possible to connect the switch to the raspberry pi, which is connected to the router wirelessly, and then plug each computer into the switch to transfer files between them at gigabit speeds. Would this work, or is it impossible? If impossible, why?

Comment: You can bridge the WiFi and Ethernet interfaces of the pi. That wouldn't give you gigabit speeds, though. It will be limited to the speed at which the pi can transmit/receive WiFi data. In most cases that will be less than 300Mbps, especially if you aren't near the router.

Comment: @SamForbis, that makes sense because the pi is connected to the router wirelessly, but the computers would be connected into the network switch with ethernet cables and the switch is connected to the raspberry pi with an ethernet cable... which is why I'm wondering if there's some possible way to allow gigabit ethernet speeds for file transfers occurring between those machines.

Comment: I'm sorry. I misunderstood your question. Yes, they would be able to use gigabit speeds between them as long as they are connected to the same switch with a wire.

Comment: @SamForbis, thank you, but do you know what kind of configuration needs to be done on the Pi to allow this? That's the part I'm unsure of.

Comment: You cannot easily bridge a Wi-Fi station interface to Ethernet. So-called Wi-Fi bridges actually employ hacks to make this possible – they pose as multiple wireless clients.

Comment: @DanielB: The ones I've seen do the opposite, they act as a single client but implement NAT for MAC addresses. I'm not sure which method is worse.

Comment: Is your main purpose of using the Raspberry Pi to get internet downstairs to your other computers?

Comment: @samforbis, no, the main purpose is to transfer multiple 40GB files between  the two compiters at gigabit speeds, not wifi speeds.

Answer (score 0):

> I am wondering if it is possible to connect the switch to the raspberry pi, which is connected to the router wirelessly, and then plug each computer into the switch to transfer files between them at gigabit speeds. Would this work, or is it impossible? If impossible, why?

Yes it would work, but it has **nothing to do with the Raspberry Pi.** That's what your *actual switch* already does all the time, so the Raspberry Pi – and even the router – might as well just not be connected at all.

As long as your computers are within the same IP subnet, they will always attempt to talk at MAC layer to each other directly – they'll send Ethernet frames with each other's MAC address as the "destination" (not the router's nor the Pi's).

All Ethernet switches are built to support this; they automatically learn which ports have which MAC addresses behind them, and will directly forward the frames to the other computer's port. They do not need to funnel everything towards the router – all switch ports are equal.

<sup>(This even applies to your router's built-in "LAN" ports. Even though they're *physically* in the same box as the router, they are almost always wired to a switch chip that works the same way as an external switch, and none of your computer-to-computer Ethernet traffic goes via the router's CPU at all.)</sup>

Comment: I believe the question was asked so that the user may get internet at his PCs on a separate floor without running a network cable between the floors from the router to the switch. The way I read the question, the OP's use of the term "switch" to describe the Pi was not a vital part of the question. They probably just didn't know what else to call it otherwise they would have said "bridge" or something like that.

Comment: OP said "between them" (as in between the connected computers), which did not sound like internet access to me.

Comment: I want to perform gigabit file transfers between the two computers, faster than I would get over wifi.